# how can i get touch location in init function in cocos2d-iphone?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I need touch coordinates in

```
-(id) init{ }
```

but  just can get them in

```
-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];

    touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

    return YES;
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

`ccTouchBegan` is called "randomly". That is, your program doesn't know when the user is going to touch the screen. This is called an asynchronous event.

I can't think of a way to get the touches that are already on the screen when init is called unless you can find a way of doing using the `CCTouchDispatcher`

Comment: thank you) this i did. now i need send location.x and .y from this function to init

Comment: Your problem is that that function isn't called until your init is finished. You'll have to find a way to either pass the touch location from a previous Scene or access the touch information directly, you won't be able to use `ccTouchBegan:`. Have a look at `CCTouchDispatcher` instead.

Comment: i rewrite it as CCTouchDispatcher